# Is it possible to verify the content of an image?

Tags: android, ios

In what language(s) is it (if at all possible) to check the content of an image?

Ideally, I am looking for web / mobile languages, but whatever is possible.

As a comparative example, I wish to make the first image of a castle 'valid' and the second image of the wall 'invalid', due to there been no substantial content in the second image. Meaning, the second image, which is the wall, has too much similarity across the image and therefore doesn't contain valid content.

Please do not provide a 'how to do it', as I am a student and will be working out solutions for myself as much as possible, I just need to know that what I want to achieve is possible in the first place and a starting point for language(s).

[image]

[image]

**EDIT2: What Javier has suggested about computer vision is on the right track to what I mean. Image analysis to break it down a little more. I wish to visually analyse an image and determine how the range of varied the colours across an image are to determine if there is actually a proper image present on not just a picture of a wall

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  I guess you haven't thought this enough to ask a concrete question, maybe you should investigate about Computer Vision, which is a very broad field of research.

Comment: May be I am not clear with your question. But its just a comment. This is the principle on which `Augmented Reality` works... You pass the image as a marker to be detected, and the camera frames are passed to the engine, which checks whether the camera frame contains the image you passed, if yes, act accordingly...